# Get the Post Count using a tag with php and WP-VIEWS (Please review / help)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need some help please. I want to echo the amount of posts on my page having a certain tag, using a shortcode. I'm using custom taxonomy tags (named 'collection'). I've written the code in a WordPress plugin. Here is my code:

```
// [upo-bts-tag-count] use [upo-bts-tag-count id="[wpv-post-taxonomy type="collection" format="text"]"] to retrieve

// Fetch the count with a shortcode
add_shortcode('upo-bts-tag-count', 'upo_bts_tag_count_function');
function upo_bts_tag_count_function () {
    $taxonomy = "collection"; // can be category, post_tag, or custom taxonomy name
    $term_name = 'id';
    $term = get_term_by('name', $term_name, $taxonomy);
    echo $term->count;
}
```

I'm able to get and display the tag name (as a string) using

```
[wpv-post-taxonomy type="collection" format="text"]
```

My current broblem is that when I activate the plugin WP say the plugin generated 3 characters of unexpected output during activation. Can someone please help me to go through the code to point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so far!

Comment: Please add the actual output to your question.

Comment: Hey Don. I want the output to be the number of posts, 1, 5 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcodes should return a value, not output it directly. That's why you're getting the error regarding generation of unexpected output.

To resolve the issue change `echo` to `return`.

Change:

```
echo $term->count;
```

To:

```
return $term->count;
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying Nathan. I changed that. No more activation errors. Code doesn't work though. Doesn't give me any value. Any ideas please?